# Using RestructuredText and Sphinx to include a preformatted file

Tags: documentation-generation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to make this fragment work:

```
Version History
---------------

These are the versions over time::

    .. include:: ../../CHANGES.txt
```

That is, use the include directive so that a file is included as a block quote.  Once inside a block quote, the directive is quoted.  I want the contents of the file in a block quote.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the .. literalinclude::  directive should give you what you want.

Comment: Worked!  Thank you.  Also, I added you to the thank you list for the next dectools release.